# Want list to display on button click in different div boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, html-lists

I have 4 div boxes with different content, but are of the same size. Below these boxes, I have a button and when the button is clicked, I want all the div boxes to display the content of 4 different unordered lists.

This seems like a fairly straight forward problem, but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is one of those four div boxes:

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box box1">
        <h6>Summer Saver</h6>
        <h2><i class="ion-social-euro"></i>1595</h2>
        <p>Save <i class="ion-social-euro"></i>300</p>
        <h5>Until August 31</h5>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="book-now">
            Book Now
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the button:

```
<button id="btnExpand" onclick="buttonText()"> Compare Benefits</button>
```

Here is everything in my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExpand").click(function() {
        $(".content").show();
    });
    $("#btnExpand").click(function() {
        $(".content").hide();
    });
});
```

As it stands, this is the only css for the boxes that I think is relevant:

```
.boxes .content ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}
```

My line of thinking is that, I currently have the list items not displayed, but clicking the button activates the div to show them and clicking it again activates them to be hidden again.

Comment: None of them were ever working, but I did change it to a class as you said and will keep it that way, but its still not working.

Comment: You're showing the .content div but every list item is hidden... there are many mistakes in your code. Please provide a fiddle and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Here is the fiddle I made with everything included in case I missed something relevant: https://jsfiddle.net/alexkarasik89/q1wbpwo5/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that with css you're hiding every single list item but you're showing the container.

Have a [look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmpp42mj/) and you'll find your answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnExpand").on('click', function() {
    if ($(".boxes .content").is(':visible')) {
      $(".boxes .content").hide();
    } else {
      $(".boxes .content").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Also, change your CSS to

```
.boxes .content {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see some of the mistakes i made clearly now. Very clear explanations. I really appreciate it.